# ¿Como validar un grupo de checkbox con javascript?

Tags: javascript

Quiero validar que al menos un checkbox de un grupo esté selecionado, pero no se sus ids o names ya que son dinámicos, van cambiando. Lo que si se es el nombre o id del div que los engloba.
¿Puedo hacerlo?

```
<div class="group-check1">
<input type="checkbox"> Opc 1
<input type="checkbox"> Opc 2
<input type="checkbox"> Opc 3
</div>
```

Tengo dos grupos de checkboxs, independientes, en ambos debe haber al menos 1 check seleccionado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como bien apunta  @aloMalbarez para verificar si alguno está ckecked solo sería necesario con el selector:

```js
const alguno = !!document.querySelector(".group-check1 input[type=checkbox]:checked");

console.log(alguno)
```

```html
<div class="group-check1">
  <input type="checkbox" checked> Opc 1
  <input type="checkbox"> Opc 2
  <input type="checkbox"> Opc 3
</div>
```

Si además hubiera que verificar alguna condición mas, además de la mera existencia, usando `querySelectorAll(".group-check1 input")` junto con `some()` sería útil

```js
const alguno = [...document.querySelectorAll(".group-check1 input")].
some(o=>(o.checked || (o.id==="uno")));

console.log(alguno)
```

```html
<div class="group-check1">
  <input id="uno" type="checkbox" checked> Opc 1
  <input id="dos" type="checkbox"> Opc 2
  <input id="tres" type="checkbox"> Opc 3
</div>
```

Es necesario aclarar que al momento de escribir esto, con un selector podemos verificar si existe o no un atributo en el tiempo, pero si tuviera valor, solo su valor inicial. Si quisiéramos hacer un selector para verificar cierto valor de `value` de por ejemplo un `input type='text'` solo podŕiamos hacer un selector para verificar el valor inicial, pero no sus cambios. En el caso del checkbox lo podemos hacer porque verificamos si existe o no el atributo, no el valor.

Comment: también serviría usar el `querySelectorAll` para apuntar directamente a los `checked` onda: `const alguno = 0 < document.querySelectorAll(".group-check1 input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;`

Comment: Si claro, en realidad me imagine el problema checkeando algo mas, pero solo para consultar si alguno está ckequeado es suficiente con la query.